# upper bound for standard normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $Z$ be a standard normal distributed random variable.
I am looking for an upper bound for the probability $\mathbb{P}(Z>t)$.
For a general $t\in\mathbb{R}$. So $t$ is possibly negative.

Comment: You can get both lower and upper bounds applicable for large positive t using essentially integration by parts. The lower bounds furnish upper bounds for the negative t case (though eventually these bounds hit 1 of course). In the intermediate range you'll need something else.

Comment: I know all the "classical" exercises handling with positive $t$. But all that proves fails for $t<0$.

Comment: Why don't you work directly with the Erf function? Its properties are extensively studied and it has series expansion, so it should be easy to find bounds for your original problem.

Comment: If you have a lower bound for the tails then you get an upper bound for the rest. And these integration by parts can give both. They are just meaningless in $(-1,1)$.

Comment: @Ian Unfortunately, I am not able to workout your hint. I would be highly pleased if you could write a more detailed answer.

Comment: For $t > 0$, Chernoff bound, Chiani bound / approximations [(http://campus.unibo.it/85943/1/mcddmsTranWIR2003.pdf)] and Karaginnadis approximations [http://users.auth.gr/users/9/3/028239/public_html/pdf/Q_Approxim.pdf] are good, but none of these are true for negative $t$.

Comment: @Xarrus For example you can look at https://www.johndcook.com/normalbounds.pdf, this gives a lower bound for $P(X>t)$ for $t>0$. This then gives the same lower bound for $P(X<-t)$, and hence an easy upper bound for $P(X>-t)$ is $1$ minus the lower bound for $P(X>t)$.

Comment: Has no one solved this yet? its got like 845 views and no one answered why